# How to compare two MultiList Selected Values

Tags: powershell-extensions

I want to compare two **MultiList** in terms of, comparing Selected Items.
I have a **MultiList** where users can select what items they want to be selected.

**Here is the image of it:**

[image]

Now I have a `Tagging` section, like almost every item, in **Media Item**, and there items can also be selected. Now I am asking, is it possible to compare **Selected Items** from the "user MultiList", like when user can select what they want, to the **MultiList** in **Media Item**

**Tagging Section:**
[image]

**Here is the code so far:**

```
@($rootItem) + @($rootItem.Axes.GetDescendants() | Initialize-Item) | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $currentItem = $_
        Get-ItemField -IncludeStandardFields -Item $currentItem -ReturnType Field -Name "*" `
            | ForEach-Object{
                ForEach($i in $value) {
                if($PSItem.Value -match $i.DisplayName -and $PSItem.Name.Contains("__Semantics")){
                    [pscustomobject]@{
                        "Name"=$currentItem.DisplayName
                        "ItemId"=$currentItem.ID
                        "FieldName"=$_.Name
                        "ItemPath" = Get-MediaUrl($currentItem)
                    }
Copy-Item -Path $currentItem.ItemPath -Destination $folderToMove.Paths.FullPath;
                }
                }
                
            } 
} | Sort-Object -Unique ItemID | Show-ListView
```

`$rootItem` is just the path to the folder, for example `sitecore/Media Library/Images`
`$value` is the value from the MultiList display names

Comment: So you want to find all the media library items under selected root which have *same* set of tags like you selected when running a report? Or at least of from those selected when running a report? Or all of those selected when running a report and potentially some more?

Comment: @MarekMusielak I only want to find those media library items that have at least one or all of the selected items. If that is really hard to make, then same set of tags.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it on my own. Here is the answer, that works for me this time

```
@($rootItem) + @($rootItem.Axes.GetDescendants() | Initialize-Item) | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $currentItem = $_
        $multilistField = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField]$currentItem.Fields["__Semantics"]

        $multilistItems = $multilistField.GetItems()

        foreach($multilistItem in $multilistItems){
           if($value.DisplayName -match $multilistItem.DisplayName){
               Write-Host $currentItem.DisplayName
                    [pscustomobject]@{
                        "Name"=$currentItem.DisplayName
                        "ItemId"=$currentItem.ID
                        "FieldName"=$_.Name
                        "ItemPath" = Get-MediaUrl($currentItem)
                    }
Copy-Item -Path $currentItem.ItemPath -Destination $folderToMove.Paths.FullPath;
                }
        }
    } | Sort-Object -Unique ItemID | Show-ListView
```